# Powershell SQLCMD Mode error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd but I get an error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -MaxCharLength 100000 -ServerInstance server1\darabse -InputFile \\server\query.sql

Invoke-Sqlcmd : 
At line:6 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -MaxCharLength 1000000 -ServerInstance server\database ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

I can run in in Management studio with SQLCMD Mode.

I have tried everything form [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/61d365b8-eecc-471b-ad68-082fb8b5f5b6/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd?forum=transactsql) . Any ideas?  There is no "$" within it.

I succeed to do i like this, but I am not sure this is solution?

```
sqlcmd -i \\server\Shared\install\file.sql
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the contents of `query.sql`? Have you tried with `-OutputSqlErrors:$true`?

Comment: same output, it is generated query from Management studio to create AlwaysOn

Comment: Could you run the command again and post the contents of $Error[0].Exception.Message ?

Comment: When I run it I get nothing? Only `$error[0]` returns me same error as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works like this:

```
cmd.exe /C sqlcmd -i \\share\Shared\install_scripts\02SQL\create.sql
```