# Restore a SQL database if does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to restore a bak file to my SQL Server instance via PowerShell.

Before putting it into a script, I was trying to just execute the command from PowerShell prompt

```
 cmd.exe /C SqlCmd -E -S COMPUTER01 -Q "RESTORE DATABASE TestDB FROM DISK = N'.\TestDB.bak' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'TESTING' TO N'.\DataStore\TestDB.mdf', MOVE N'TESTING_log' TO N'.\LogStore\TestDB.ldf', NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5"
```

It threw an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I then changed my cmd to add a semicolon

```
cmd.exe /C SqlCmd -E -S COMPUTER01 -Q "RESTORE DATABASE TestDB FROM DISK = N'.\TestDB.bak'**;** WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'TESTING' TO N'.\DataStore\TestDB.mdf', MOVE N'TESTING_log' TO N'.\LogStore\TestDB.ldf', NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5"
```

Now, it is throwing error:

> "Incorrect syntax near ..."

Can someone please give me a working piece code where I can

1. Check if a DB already exists with the name "TestDB"
2. If it exists, delete the DB
3. Restore my TestDB.bak with the name TestDB

I am using script this in PowerShell 5 and not in a need to use only `cmd.exe /C SqlCmd`. If there is any better way then I will adapt that too.

Comment: Why do you think you need `cmd /c` there? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Also, your question says PowerShell v5, while your tags say PowerShell v3. Which is it?

Comment: I edited the tag to drop powershell 3.0. Sorry about that wrong tagging. Btw I saw the cmd.exe /C syntax being used in other solutions in SO. For example 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347095/powershell-sqlcmd-mode-error

I think that is how we execute sqlcmds from a powershell.

Comment: You're restoring from disk and you're specifying `NOUNLOAD` which is [documented as a tape option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx), that doesn't seem right.

Comment: PowerShell can run external commands just fine by itself. `cmd /c` is only required in some rare corner cases (or when you want to use a CMD builtin command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want, but it doesn't ask you if the DB exists. That takes a lot more lines of code and does it really matter since you will be deleting the DB\rewriting it anyways.

```
$DBName="TestDB"
$backupFilePath="D:\TESTDB.bak"
$Datafilepath="D:\DataStore" #Do not add the trailing \
$Logfilepath="D:\LogStore" #Do not add the trailing \
$dbCommand = "use [master];RESTORE DATABASE [$DBName] " + "FROM DISK = N'$backupFilePath'" + "WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, " + "move 'TESTING' to '$Datafilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + "_data1.mdf', " + "move 'TESTING_log' to '$Logfilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + "_log1.ldf';" + "alter database [$DBName] modify file (name=N'TESTING', newname=N'$DBName" + "_data1');" + "alter database [$DBName] modify file (name=N'TESTING_log', newname=N'$DBName" + "_log1');" + "alter database [$DBName] set read_committed_snapshot on with rollback immediate;" + "alter database [$DBName] set COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;"
sqlcmd -S $DBServerName -E -Q $dbCommand -r0
```